"I have no idea what you were talking about" or "I have no idea what you talked about"?
To reply to another person's words, which one is correct "I have no idea what you were talking about" or "I have no idea what you talked about"?
i.e. Should I use past continuous tense or just simple past tense?
To make my question more clear, I see people use past continuous tense but I don't understand that because the one I reply these words to has already said something, so why use past continuous tense?

The former sentence is the more common usage. The second one would describe what you talked about at an earlier time; yesterday or last night.

Are you trying to say that you heard them talk but you did not understand the meaning?  Or that you did not even hear them talk?

Hi I have updated my question to make it more clearer why I have this question in the first place. @JohnGordon the former.
